# vsftpd missing banner for SSL/TLS connections resulting in client errors

Tags: ftp

I am wondering if anybody was running into this issue with vsftpd:

Here is the log from the client:

```
FTPS

Status:Resolving address of ftpservice.domain.com
Status:Connecting to 1.1.1.1:990...
Status:Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Error:Connection timed out
Error:Could not connect to server

FTP PLAIN:

Status:Resolving address of ftpservice.domain.com
Status:Connecting to 1.1.1.1:21...
Status:Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:220 "FTP Server"
Command:USER test_user
Response:331 Please specify the password.
Command:PASS **********
Response:230 Login successful.
Command:SYST
Response:215 UNIX Type: L8
Command:FEAT
Response:211-Features:
Response:AUTH SSL
Response:AUTH TLS
Response:EPRT
Response:EPSV
Response:MDTM
Response:PASV
Response:PBSZ
Response:PROT
Response:REST STREAM
Response:SIZE
Response:TVFS
Response:UTF8
Response:211 End
Command:OPTS UTF8 ON
Response:200 Always in UTF8 mode.
Status:Connected
Status:Retrieving directory listing...
Command:PWD
Response:257 "/"
Command:TYPE I
Response:200 Switching to Binary mode.
Command:PASV
Response:227 Entering Passive Mode (1,1,1,1,25,103).
Command:LIST
Response:150 Here comes the directory listing.
Response:226 Directory send OK.
Status:Directory listing successful
```

Has anybody seen this behavior before?

Comment: Yes, i've already seen this behaviour, but the "real" cause was not the missing banner, but Passive mode and Firewall rules. Do you have a Firewall in front of your FTP Server ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add the following option to the vsftpd config:

```
ssl_ciphers=HIGH
```